# URL fails to find my web app context – Java Enterprise Beans - Wildfly

Tags: java, rest, ejb, wildfly

I have an EJB application in combination with RESTful services and a MySQL Database. I would like to deploy this application on my Wildfly Server. I have configured everything and so far no error's when I would like to start the application via Eclipse on my Wildfly server. The problem is that I can not access the ressource via my browser - I would like to call http://localhost:8080/REST-EJB-ArticleService/v1/articles in my browser to access my ressource but I get 404. It seems that the application is not published on my webserver.

Here is an excerpt of the output when I start my application:

I start the application via right click on project - Run on Server(Wildfly is running correctly)

> 9:08:33,715 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread
>   1-6) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.9.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.12) 
>   19:08:34,012 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-7)
>   WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for primary 19:08:34,430 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6)
>   WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1) 19:08:34,445 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6)
>   WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class
>   com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1) 19:08:34,445
>   INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3)
>   WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name =
>   mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
>   19:08:34,445 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC
>   service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with
>   driver-name =
>   mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar_com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver_5_1
>   19:08:34,445 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8)
>   WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment MovieWebService.jar
>   19:08:34,508 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources]
>   (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source
>   [java:/MySqlDS] 19:08:34,523 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of
>   2) Service 'MovieWebService.jar#primary' 19:08:34,539 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool
>   -- 62) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [    name: primary   ...] 19:08:34,539 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread
>   1-8) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.5.Final 19:08:34,601 INFO 
>   [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread
>   1-7) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.8.Final
>   19:08:34,633 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread
>   1-8) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named
>   'ArticleResourceEJB' in deployment unit 'deployment
>   "MovieWebService.jar"' are as follows:
>
> java:global/MovieWebService/ArticleResourceEJB!com.dev.ejbwebservice.ArticleResourceEJB
>   ***>    java:app/MovieWebService/ArticleResourceEJB!com.dev.ejbwebservice.ArticleResourceEJB
>     java:module/ArticleResourceEJB!com.dev.ejbwebservice.ArticleResourceEJB
>     java:global/MovieWebService/ArticleResourceEJB
>     java:app/MovieWebService/ArticleResourceEJB
>     java:module/ArticleResourceEJB***
>
> 19:08:34,633 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool
>   -- 62) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.10.Final} 19:08:34,633 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62)
>   HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found 19:08:34,633 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62)
>   HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist 19:08:34,680 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool
>   -- 62) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final} 19:08:34,789 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2)
>   WELD-000900: 2.4.3 (Final) 19:08:34,930 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63)
>   WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
>   19:08:34,945 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool --
>   62) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service
>   'MovieWebService.jar#primary' 19:08:35,101 ERROR [stderr]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Thu Sep 07 19:08:35 CEST 2017 WARN:
>   Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is
>   not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+
>   requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit
>   option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using
>   SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need
>   either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set
>   useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate
>   verification.
>
> 19:08:35,196 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) IJ000407: No lazy enlistment
>   available for MySqlDS

But I would expect something like that in a tutorial, a link where I can see on which address my ejb is running.

[image]

Here is my ejb class:

```
@Path("/v1/articles")
@Stateless
public class ArticleResourceEJB
{

    @Inject
    private ArticleDAO dao;

    public ArticleResourceEJB()
    {
        System.out.println(ArticleResourceEJB.class.getName() + " created");
    }


    @POST
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public void insert(ArticleDTO user)
    {
        System.out.println("insert: " + user);

        dao.createArticle(user.getDescription(), user.getPrice());
    }


    @PUT
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public void update(ArticleDTO dto)
    {
        System.out.println("update to " + dto);

        dao.update(dto.toArticle());
    }


    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void delete(@PathParam("id") int id)
    {
        System.out.println("delete: " + id);

        // TODO
    }


    @GET
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public List<ArticleDTO> findAll()
    {
        System.out.println("findAll()");

        List<Article> list = dao.findAll();
        List<ArticleDTO> result = ArticleDTO.toArticleDTOList(list);
        System.out.println("size = " + result.size());
        return result;
    }


    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public ArticleDTO findById(@PathParam("id") int id) 
    {
        System.out.println("findById(" + id + ")");

        Article article = dao.findById(id);
        return new ArticleDTO(article);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you got the Context name wrong. I think the name of your deployed artifact (Name of your App) is 'MovieWebService', hence the url should be something like localhost:8080/MovieWebService/pathToYourService/pathToMethod

Not so sure if it must be a `.jar` , I would normally make the deployable artifact a `.war` or `.ear` to be deployed to Wildfly.

Comment: It definitely needs to be a WAR not a JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Your example log is from a web services service, so doesn't apply to a rest service. Start with the wildfly quickstart. Don't know if you have it, but jax-rs needs to extend `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`:

```
/**
 * JAXActivator is an arbitrary name, what is important is that javax.ws.rs.core.Application is extended
 * and the @ApplicationPath annotation is used with a "rest" path.  Without this the rest routes linked to
 * from index.html would not be found.
 */

@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class JAXActivator extends Application {
    // Left empty intentionally
}
```

Reference: [helloworld-rs: Helloworld Using JAX-RS (Java API for RESTful Web Services)](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/11.x/helloworld-rs)